# Views overlapping in app widget layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an app widget and the layout is going to have a `View` aligned at the bottom of the widget, to hold a `TextView` and a `ImageView`, then a `View` above it to hold the main text.  The problem with what I have is that is seems the "top" `View` is overlapping with the bottom `View`:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Now I'm thinking the "top" view is not overlapping the bottom view, but that something is cutting off the top of the image.  Here is another screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the text is being cutoff at the top of the bottom view, but the image is getting cut of as well.  Here is a screenshot with the image not being scaled to 18dp:

[image]

I'm extremely confused.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/widgetLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/widgetBgLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_widget"
         >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/widgetStatusLayout" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
          >
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/widgetStatus" 
                    style="@style/WidgetStatus"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                />

                <ImageView 
                   android:id="@+id/widgetIcon"
                   android:src="@drawable/icon"
                   android:layout_width="18dp"
                   android:layout_height="18dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:scaleType="centerInside"
                   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_above="@id/widgetStatusLayout"       
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             >      
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/widgetTitle" 
                        style="@style/WidgetTitle"
                    />

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/widgetText" 
                        style="@style/WidgetText"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to set the height of the icon to a higher number (28dp).  I don't think the icon is a true rectangle (I had someone else make the icons for me), which probably caused issues with the aspect ratio.